# Calling AWS services from parse cloud code?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, aws-lambda

Which is the best way of making call to AWS services like S3,Dynamodb,cloudwatch etc from parse cloud code (offcourse while taking care of cloud function timeouts)?

Importing AWS sdk in parse cloud code is showing lot of wierd errors relating to internal file dependencies which is very time consuming to resolve.

Is calling them via aws lambda function REST call advisable? or Please quote me an example if some better technique is available.

Thanks

Comment: Any progress on this?